# str_replace "</p>" with "</p><br />"

Tags: php, str-replace

The database of a client has entries that are formatted in html code. Cleaning these entries so that they are without html is no option as there are just too many entries.

These entries miss line breaks after every ending paragraph tag (< /p >). Therefor I thought it would be a clever idea to use str_replace to replace "< /p >" with "< /p >< br />".

The code for this that I have where $ results gives the entry from the database table:

```
$result_information = "$results";
$result_information = str_replace("</p>", "<br />", "</p><br />");
echo $result_information;
```

This returns nothing. If I change "< br />" with something else it returns that value only once. It looks like its only doing the replacement once. Is there any way to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the documents would have helped you with this question [see here str_repalce](http://php.net/str_replace)

```
mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )
```

> This function returns a string or an array with all occurrences of search in subject replaced with the given replace value.

As for your fix:

```
$result_information = "$results";
$result_information = str_replace("</p>", "</p><br />", $result_information);
echo $result_information;
```

Answer (score 2):

To replace `</p>` with `</p><br />` use this:

```
$result_information = str_replace("</p>", "</p><br />", $result_information);
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you want, as you title question, replace `</p> by </p><br />`, you have to do it like this :

```
$result_information = "$results";
$result_information = str_replace('</p>', '</p><br />', $result_information);
echo $result_information;
```